# GUI button calling another GUI with autohotkey

Tags: user-interface, autohotkey

I am attempting to make a Decision Tree type program with multiple GUI's in autohotkey. I have figured out how to make it work one time, but for some reason I can't do it more than once. This is the code that works:

```
Gui, Add, Text, x72 y20 w220 h20 , What type of request?
Gui, Add, Button, x12 y50 w100 h30 , Password
Gui, Add, Button, x132 y50 w100 h30 , AppError
Gui, Add, Button, x252 y50 w100 h30 , AccessRequest
Gui, Add, Button, x252 y90 w100 h30 , NotSure
Gui, Add, Button, x132 y90 w100 h30 , HardwareProblem
Gui, Add, Button, x12 y90 w100 h30 , RightsChangeRequest
Gui, Show,center, Decision Tree
Return
ExitApp

ButtonPassword:
Gui, Destroy
Gui, Add, Text, x72 y20 w220 h20 , Passwords: What is the user trying to access?
Gui, Add, Button, x12 y50 w100 h30 , Windows
Gui, Add, Button, x132 y50 w100 h30 , Outlook
Gui, Add, Button, x252 y50 w100 h30 , RemoteApps
Gui, Add, Button, x252 y90 w100 h30 , NotSure
Gui, Add, Button, x132 y90 w100 h30 , AO
Gui, Add, Button, x12 y90 w100 h30 , Voicemail
Gui, Add, button, x132 y130 w100 h30, Back
Gui, Show,center, Passwords
Return

ButtonWindows:
Gui, destroy

Msgbox, 4, Something, Is this a remote user?
IfMsgbox Yes
    Msgbox, Something
IfMsgbox No
    Msgbox, Say something
return
```

I have more code for the rest of the buttons which work just fine. Here's the part that doesnt:

```
ButtonAppError:
Gui, destroy

Gui, Add, Button, x142 y220 w100 h30 , ANA1
Gui, Add, Button, x22 y60 w100 h30 , ANA2
Gui, Add, Button, x22 y100 w100 h30 , ANA3
Gui, Add, Button, x22 y140 w100 h30 , ANA4
Gui, Add, Button, x22 y180 w100 h30 , ANA5
Gui, Add, Button, x22 y220 w100 h30 , ANA6
Gui, Add, Text, x62 y20 w130 h20 , What Program is erroring?
Gui, Show,center,Applications
Return

ButtonANA1:
Gui, destroy
Gui, Add, Text, x132 y20 w30 h20 , ANA
Gui, Add, Button, x162 y60 w100 h90 , Somestuff
Gui, Add, Button, x22 y170 w100 h90 , Somestuff2
Gui, Add, Button, x22 y60 w100 h90 , Somestuff3
Gui, Add, Button, x162 y170 w100 h90 , Somestuff4
Gui, Show, x260 y159 h307 w282, ANA
Return
```

Button ANA1 (or ANA2 or ANA3 etc) doesn't work for some reason. I see no difference in formatting between the top and bottom. I feel like this is a dumb question, but I've already asked three other people to take a look at this and nobody can seem to figure it out.

Comment: If you copy all the code you showed us into a new script, the ANA1 button works. The problem should be somewhere else. I recommend you read the Autohotkey help file on how to create multiple GUIs (which shows you how to assign a name to the GUI and might make it easier to locate the problem )

Comment: "Doesn't work for some reason". Is it giving you some sort of error? Just not firing the code?

Comment: I recommend seeing the autohotkey documentation of Multiple GUIs using GUI "labels"... here: http://l.autohotkey.net/docs/commands/Gui.htm#MultiWin